# Know the trigger when user has pressed cancel buttons during In-App purchase

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

I have integrated IAP functionality in my flutter app. I wants to know when user has clicked the "Cancel" button on IAP popup.
There are many solution found here but that all code is in native.
It will be very helpful If I get the trigger of cancel button click in flutter iOS.
On the cancel button click I need to do other functionalities.

I have followed the IAP integration code from this link:
https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-inapp-purchases/
and the IAP popup is shown as default popup not a custom.

Please give some suggestion. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a loop to look for failed transactions and then finish them accordingly.

I am still experimenting with where to do this to try to avoid a user error. I am also going to try to do a similar process in the stream listener that processes purchases.

There are StoreKit Wrappers included with IAP plugin:

Note: I looked at SK info for XCode and it seems fine to do this with a failed transaction. They said it is a 'no no' to do it to a pending one.

```
  Future<Null> _removeFailedPendingPurchases() async {
debugPrint(':::: SWIPE WAR ::::: _removeFailedPendingPurchases()');
final SKPaymentQueueWrapper paymentWrapper = SKPaymentQueueWrapper();
final List<SKPaymentTransactionWrapper> transactions =
    await paymentWrapper.transactions();
debugPrint(
    ':::: SWIPE WAR ::::: transactions ${transactions.length} ${transactions.toString()}');

for (SKPaymentTransactionWrapper transaction in transactions) {
  debugPrint('TRANSACTION everything : ${transaction.toString()}');
  debugPrint('TRANSACTION STATE : ${transaction.transactionState}');
  if (transaction.transactionState ==
      SKPaymentTransactionStateWrapper.failed)
    await paymentWrapper.finishTransaction(transaction);
}

return;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you press cancel button the `PurchaseDetails.status` will be equal to `PurchaseStatus.error`.  So you check it:

```
 if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
 //Change UI state to reflect this problem
}
```